# Flip animation with flutter_redux

Tags: animation, flutter

I have a time displaying app, which changes the time everytime the time changes. I would really like to know how I can add a "text-flip" animation to the digits. When the app starts up, the digits flip into place immediately, but fail to flip every time there is a change. Here is my code:

```
/// Flutter Packages
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';


class ListTimeWidget extends StatefulWidget { ... }


class _ListTimeWidgetState extends State<ListTimeWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  /// Methods
  String _selectCorrectTime(Store<DateTime> store) {
    Map<String, int> timeDelta = {
      'years': store.state.year,
      'months': store.state.month,
      'days': store.state.day,
      'hours': store.state.hour,
      'minutes': store.state.minute,
    };

    if (timeDelta.containsKey(widget.timeUnit))
      return timeDelta[widget.timeUnit].toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    else
      return '##';
  }

  /// Widgets
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this._controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    this._animation = new Tween(
        begin: 0.0,
        end: 1.0,
    ).animate(this._controller);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: this._animation,

        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
            ..scale(1.0, this._animation.value, 1.0);

          return new Transform(
            transform: transform,
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: child,
          );
        },

        child: new StoreConnector<DateTime, String>(
          converter: (store) => this._selectCorrectTime(store),
          builder: (context, time) {
            this._controller.forward();
            return new Text(
              time,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),
            );
            },
        )

    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    this._controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And the result I get is an animation in the very beginning and when the digits reappear from off screen, but not when the time is changing:

[image: Flip Animation]

I am new to animations in Flutter and any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to set a bool property on your state that becomes true when a new state happen?

Comment: When a new state happens, the builder is called (and I added some print() statements and saw some results)

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to accomplish a timed animation in conjunction with flutter_redux. By splitting the `StoreConnector` to it's own `Stateless Widget`, and the animation in it's own `Stateful Widget`, the the `forward` method no longer throws an issue.

Here is my sample code:

```
/// Flutter Packages
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';

/// Dart Packages
import 'dart:async';

class ListTimeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Attributes
  final String timeUnit;

  /// Constructors
  const ListTimeWidget({
    this.timeUnit,
  });

  /// Methods
  String _selectCorrectTime(Store<DateTime> store) {
    Map<String, int> timeDelta = {
      'years': store.state.year,
      'months': store.state.month,
      'days': store.state.day,
      'hours': store.state.hour,
      'minutes': store.state.minute,
    };

    if (timeDelta.containsKey(this.timeUnit))
      return timeDelta[this.timeUnit].toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    else
      return '##';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      new StoreConnector<DateTime, String>(
          converter: (store) => this._selectCorrectTime(store),
          builder: (context, time) => new ListTimeWidgetAnimation(amountOfTime: time),
      );
}

class ListTimeWidgetAnimation extends StatefulWidget { ... }


class _ListTimeWidgetAnimationState extends State<ListTimeWidgetAnimation> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  /// Attributes
  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;
  String _currentTime;

  /// Methods
  Future<Null> _changeTimeAnimation() async {
    await this._controller.reverse();

    setState(() {
      this._currentTime = widget.amountOfTime;
    });

    await this._controller.forward();
  }

  /// Widgets
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this._controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    this._animation = new Tween(
        begin: 0.0,
        end: 1.0,
    ).animate(this._controller);

    this._currentTime = widget.amountOfTime;
    this._controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (this._currentTime != widget.amountOfTime) {
      this._changeTimeAnimation();
    }

    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: this._animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
          ..scale(1.0, this._animation.value, 1.0);
        return new Transform(
          transform: transform,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: new Text(
        this._currentTime,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    this._controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Which produces the following effect during a time change:

[image: New Flip Animation]

Answer (score 0):

You should either call `.reset()` on the AnimationController or pass in the from argument in the `.forward() change into .forward(from: 0.0))` when you call it in the build method. Calling `.forward()` on an Animationcontroller moves it to upperbounds. Calling `.forward()` on it again, without reseting or passing in the "from", causes it to do nothing since you are already on maxvalue (uppebound).

Comment: When I do either, I get the following exception:

`Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

I believe I'm changing the state too frequently and will change that.

EDIT: I still get the exception after updating after 1 minute

Comment: I've not used redux before, but here is a gist of a working solution without redux (took your code and modified it essentially), where i'm just incrementing a counter with the animation running once every 1 second without any issues. https://gist.github.com/mattiasLundell/b62eb1034ab1204fa2ee5d6a2a0d3671. hope that helps you out.